# Retrofit ws error using @Query

Tags: android, retrofit

I have try this interface :

```
public interface InterfaceWs
{
  @GET("/?extract-mode=bestdeals&api-key={apikey}") public Observable<List<ModelBestDeals>> getBestDeals(@Query("apikey") String apikey);
}
```

Before using `@Query` I was using `@Path`. I change it 
and I receive this error :

```
URL query string "extract-mode=bestdeals&api-key={apikey}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 @GET("/?extract-mode=bestdeals&api-key={apikey}") public Observable<List<ModelBestDeals>> getBestDeals(@Query("apikey") String apikey);
```

should be

```
@GET("/?extract-mode=bestdeals") public Observable<List<ModelBestDeals>> getBestDeals(@Query("api-key") String apikey);
```

retrofit will take care of completing your url with  `api-key=value`, where value is the value of `apikey`. You could also use a QueryMap to provide the other pair `extract-mode=bestdeals`. E.g.

```
 Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
 map.put("extract-mode", "bestdeals");
 map.put("api-key", apikey);
```

and your method

```
  @GET("/") public Observable<List<ModelBestDeals>>  
  getBestDeals(@QueryMap Map<String, String> values);
```

which is, in my opinion, way more readable